# How can I get (Express's) sessionID for a websocket connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, express

I'm using WebSockets `npm install ws` on the same port as Express is running.

I'd like to pick up the associated 'sessionID' from the HTTP connection which had just been made and upgraded to a WebSocket.

```
// start express listening
server.listen(conf.server.port, conf.server.host);

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    var sessionID = // how do I get this?
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
    ws.send('something');
});
```

How can this be done?

(I currently work around the issue by sending the sessionID in the page, but this is ugly.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Parse cookie
2. Get session id
3. Get session data

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var parseCookie = express.cookieParser();
   var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;

   var store = new MemoryStore();

   app.configure(function() {
       app.use(express.session({ store: store, secret: '123456', key: 'sid' }));
   });

   wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
       parseCookie(ws.upgradeReq, null, function(err) {
           var sessionID = ws.upgradeReq.cookies['sid'];
           store.get(sessionID, function(err, session) {
               // session
           });
       }); 

       ws.on('message', function(message) {
           console.log('received: %s', message);
       });
       ws.send('something');
   });
   ```

Comment: That's on the right track, but there's no 'sid' cookie.  There are: `connect.sid: n8Pbh5hPhNNC3B6PAkyuaRgv.o9wnmI3fiJ47kJMUfW0xVcMRkhjFkMbgvki/CTtemvU` and `sessionid: 12d2b0c6f3c3eb661215a401d1942122`.  Which of these is the key to the session, and what is the other?

Comment: 'connect.sid' is default key for express cookie. In above code express was configure with session key is 'sid'... if you don't customize it, key is 'connect.sid'.

Comment: Won't that cookie be signed with the secret? If so you'll have to remove the signed part before using it as a key with store.get

Comment: After a lot of fiddling, I got a variation of this working. The key was to put the secret into `express.cookieParser('123456')` and use `upgradeReq.signedCookies['sid']`

Comment: I synthesized the comments and included a new code example, see below!

Comment: In recent versions of express, MemorySession location also changed along with separation of middleware: require('express-session').MemoryStore

Answer (score 7):

This was a nightmare, finally got it working for myself using signed cookies!

Set up your store (example memory store):

```
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;
store = new MemoryStore();
```

Expose parseCookie as global (if you need it in other modules) like this in app / server js files:

```
app.use(parseCookie = express.cookieParser('secret'));
```

Now set up sockets:

```
//this method gets called later
var ensureAuthenticatedSocket = function(handshake, callback) {
    cookie = cookieParser(handshake, null, function(err) {
        var sessionID = handshake.signedCookies['sid'];
        store.get(sessionID, function(err, session) {
            callback(err, session);
        });
    });
};
//listen time
io = io.listen(server);
//configure authentication
io.configure(function() {
    io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
        //call the method with handshake as parameter, wait for callback
        ensureAuthenticatedSocket(handshake, function(err, session) {
            if (!err && session) {
                //no error + found session = wicked!
                callback(null, true);
            } else {
                callback(null, false);
            }
        });
    });
});
...
//more socket code
```

Comment: Everything about Node is currently a nightmare. all the information lacks SO MANY essential stuff..lack of explanations everywhere, things are taken for granted.

Comment: @vsync L2 web app sir.

Comment: I find it's still better than php and since I do a lot of projects front and backend the common language is much better for me.