# How can I get (Express's) sessionID for a SockJS connection

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, sockjs

I am using SockJS on Express server. Is there any way to get the associate HTTP session ID of the client?

I see there is a way to do it for raw [web socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541835/how-can-i-get-expresss-sessionid-for-a-websocket-connection) and [Socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-handshake), but I am struggling to find how to do it for SockJS.

This is how my server looks like. I want a similar handler to fetch session ID:

```js
var sockjs_echo = sockjs.createServer(sockjs_opts);
sockjs_echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
    conn.on('data', function(message) {
        conn.write(message);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're using redis to manage your sessions our team wrote a library that may help. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-token-sockjs. That library will associate sessions with a socket when it connects and will expose it on all RPC or publish-subscribe actions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "hack", but it works for me:

```
sockjs_echo.on('connection', function(conn) {

        var cookieHeader = conn._session.recv.ws._stream._readableState.pipes._driver._request.headers.cookie
        var cookies = {}
        cookieHeader.split(';').forEach(function( cookie ) {
            var parts = cookie.split('=');
            cookies[parts.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(parts.join('='));
        });

        conn.on('data', function(message) {
            conn.write(message);
        });
    });
```

'cookies' variable (example):

```
{
  "dev_cookie": "1mimec6rbcolp0ujkcbqq9pdq4uoa5v0p8a284v32tmd4q3k0qi9p4vjteoifdn9b0lsm238fghf974o9jfehfuhvm3ltrgq02ad6k0",
  "session_cookie": "s%3AjkKYPKFFT8r60rXUsVYISoOF17o49GUl.pbpu6T1%2BcdrIu5uQPRxZUYOrl5GnC179GaI5pWyR7SA",
  "other_cookie": "s%3AzRMiC3fjo4gxTXX1p2XSi_C_EydIa358.KAdP1gwtZBVfcbkmwi%2B3pa0L1pbOCzQ3lHnNEyFvvHc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for asking this question, @darwinbaisa, and for the answer, c-toesca. This came after days of searching.

For XHR streaming, the cookies are at: conn._session.recv.request.headers.cookie.

The only other way I could think of doing this was to make the express session cookie httpOnly: false, thus exposing it to javascript and, of course, the possibility of hacking, then pass it back as a prefix to any message from the SockJS javascript client to the node server.

Or to assign the ID to a javascript variable as I dynamically wrote a web page response, so that javascript would have access to the variable, and again could return it to the server. But again, this would have exposed the ID, and even if the ID was hashed or encrypted, it could still be used in a malicious call to the server from javascript.

Things like this are made a lot easier in the node WS library, but I need a fallback from that for websocket-challenged browsers.