# node.js socket.io app - How to kick someone from chat room?

Tags: node.js, sockets

So I have chat app in which only two users can be in a room at a time.

Please note that clientInfo is a global variable and anytime a new user joins a room, an object variable is passed to the server with username and room name. Then this code is executed

```
socket.on('joinRoom', function(userDetails){

  clientInfo[socket.id] = userDetails; //variable contains name and room joined. 
  socket.join(userDetails.room);
}
```

I added a feature where a user can type 'kick' as the chat message which will call this function:

```
function kickUser(socket){           

  socket.leave(clientInfo[socket.id].room);
  delete clientInfo[socket.id];

}
```

the above code works fine but how can i change the function to kick the other user in the room? I tried the code below but I still ended up kicking myself out. I take it that socket.leave() doesn't care about the socket id but it just uses the room name and the person who called the function.

```
function kickUser(socket){

  var info = clientInfo[socket.id];  

  if (typeof info == 'undefined'){    
    return;
  }

   Object.keys(clientInfo).forEach(function(socketId){          
     if(info.room == clientInfo[socketId].room) {
        if (info.name != clientInfo[socketId].name){          
          socket.leave(clientInfo[socketId].room);
          delete clientInfo[socketId];  
        } 
      }
   });  
}
```

Comment: Do you want that each user can kick another user and self? Or do you need kick user by server (=admin)?

Comment: I guess my answer would be yes to both questions. I basically want to be able to chose which of the two users I want to kick out. Currently if any user tries to kick someone out, that someone will be himself.

Answer (score 0):

Try implement next idea

---

In `socket.on('connection', function(socket){ ... });` you must identify user name and room for this connection/socket: client can send username/room on connection itself

```
socket.on('connect', function {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify{do: "introduce", name: "User1", room: "dasRoom"})
})
```

or server can read it in [**client cookie**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541835/how-can-i-get-expresss-sessionid-for-a-websocket-connection). Also you can check here user count in room. This info can be stored in global vars.

User can do kick by send specified message by socket, e.g. `{do: "kick
, user: "User1"}`, or request url. e.g. `/kick/User1`.

Function `Kick` must implement logic to find user by name, send goodbay message to victim and disconnect socket. Also server must send `User1 leave room` to alive user by socket.